# Creating a vector of random samples of variable length

Tags: r

I have an R script where

`l2` is an array of all permutations of three letter combinations a-z ie the first values is `aaa` and the last values is `zzz`

`c <- rpois(n, 5)` is a vector of poisson distribution results.

I want to create a data frame that containtns a random number of samples from `l2` and concatenates them into a path like this: `abc -> vye -> tyb` for 3.

```
df_p <- data.frame('len' = c, 's1' = paste(sample(l2,c), collapse = ' -> '))
```

I've tried to use the above row to create it, but it returns the same path for every row. The length of this path corresponds to the first value in c.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out ...

```
unlist(lapply(c, function(x) paste(sample(l2,x), collapse = ' -> ')  ))
```

... does the trick.

Comment: You can use the simpler `sapply(...)` instead of `unlist(lapply(...))`.